# Spring : Configure xml to make a controller return a view depending on a parameter

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC based application and I want to add a functionality in which some of my controllers will return the same view depending on the value of a parameter.

```
@RequestMapping("/someView")
public String returnView(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, String param){
    if(param.equals("condition")){
        return "commonView";
    }

    // do stuff

    return "methodSpecificView";
}
```

Is there a way in which the first if condition can be configured in an xml? Since similar functionality needs to implemented in many controllers and I don't want to write boilerplate code an xml configuration can make things simpler.

Furthermore, if the first one is possible, can it be extended to eliminate the parameter `param` from request mapping method signature and put that in xml too?

Answer (score 1):

You can use @RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/someView", "/anotherView", ...}, params = "name=condition")
public String returnCommonView(){
    return "commonView";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spring 3.2 which is annotation based the below code snippet will give you an idea for your problem:

```
    @RequestMapping("formSubmit.htm")   
public String onformSubmit(@ModelAttribute("TestBean") TestBean testBean,BindingResult result, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String _result  = null;
    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            _result = performAction(request, dataStoreBean);//Method to perform action based on parameters recieved
        }
       if(testBean.getCondition()){
         _result = "commonView";
       }else{
        _result = "methodSpecificView";
      }     
        return _result; 

    }
 TestBean//Class to hold all the required setters and getters
```

**Explanation:**
As the request from your view comes to this method the ModelAttribute reference will hold all the values from view if the condition is obtained from the view than you can directly obtain it from model attribute and return the corresponding view.
If your condition is obtained after applying certain logic than you can set the condition in the testBean and again get it to return the corresponding view.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider implementing this via `AOP - Around` advice something like below.

```
@Around("@annotation(RequestMapping)") // modify the condition to include / exclude specific methods
public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinpoint) throws Throwable {

    Object args[] = joinpoint.getArgs();
    String param = args[2]; // change the index as per convenience
    if(param.equals("condition")){
       return "commonView";
    } else {
      return joinpoint.proceed(); // this will execute the annotated method
    }
}
```